# DocuSignApi Test class for Salesforce

Tags: soap, salesforce, docusignapi

i try to deploy the DocuSign solution on Salesforce,
i have generated the DocuSign Class by wsdl2apex to use the SOAP API

is there a solution to code coverage the generated class ?
is the Test class exist somewhere ?

Did i miss something in the Docusign for salesforce package ?
(maybe the Soap API is included)

Thx

Comment: For information, link to the generated class https://support-avenirgreen.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/0Y000000ZhQt/a/1v000000qbU5/JNMmhq5oyGDyzl0_1kVRcl7odK_sM3IfnMaTgWWmvuI

Answer (score 0):

Found nothing better than a boring code coverage class

https://support-avenirgreen.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/0Y000000ZhQt/a/1v000000qbVS/i3eR2apM93hqUrANrQdGoh3R_KXEPEiCoj3owHiRB_A

https://support-avenirgreen.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/0Y000000ZhQt/a/1v000000qbVX/IqQHhlha3IBcAVjNJcudpXc2VwS63f.BFQq.um.ZZF4